# How do I check if a string is equal to another string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I'm trying to check if one string (current_user.email) is equal to another string, (@user.email). 
How would I do this with an if/else statement? 
I tried

```
<% if @current_user.email(=@user.bio) %>    
  <a href="google.com"> Link </a>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```

but I got a syntax error. help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The invalid syntax is `(=@`.  The `=` is for assignment and has no use in method invocation.

Your `if` line should look like

```
<% if @current_user.email == @user.email %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<% if @current_user.email == @user.bio %>` try this & see.